# Display time differs from actual solving time taken in Minizinc model

Tags: minizinc, gecode

I wrote a large minizinc model including var variables with int_search statement for proper ordering. It contains output statement in which I use fix(var variables) statements to output the variable values and it contains some functions which use built-in functions sum, bool2int, etc.
Now when I run the model it displays on the screen after a very long time ( say, 5-6 minutes) but runtime/solvetime (by default print information of solver) shows only 20 seconds.
Why is this strange thing happening? Is it because output statement also consumes time? But the variables got fixed at that time, then why so?

Answer (score 2):

The extra time is probably due to the first step in the process: i.e. converting the MiniZinc (.mzn) file to FlatZinc (.fzn); this is the "flattening step". The time the solver shows is from when it start to read the FlatZinc file.

Large models might require considerable time to flatten, as you've witnessed here.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any particular way to reduce that? Because I am wasting a lot of time there almost 15 times as solving. My model contains lots of annotations also, that also contributes to considerable time while flattening?

Comment: @RajatGupta, The flattening time will depend a lot on your model and the solver library that you are targeting. Usually it's the solvers using the `linear` library that take a lot of time, like Gurobi, CBC, or CPLEX.

Comment: @RajatGupta, To reduce the flattening time, annotations won't make a difference. It is the  number of variables, constraints, and level of reifications. You can try to reduce this or try the `--no-optimise` flag. This might result in worse Flatzinc, but should improve flattening time. If you are running the same instance multiple time, you can run `mzn2fzn` seperately and safe the flat model.

Comment: Heyy!! I have tried the commands separately, mzn2fzn but it takes almost 2-3s to complete. But when I tried fzn-gecode with passing .ozn file or without passing .ozn file. It takes a huge time when run with passing .ozn file. So the main culprit is .ozn file. How can this happen? I think output param variables(var variables those get fixed after solving) can never be issue. There is function overloading inside it also, and builtin sum function. Still I am not able to find what causes output to slow at such a huge rate.

Comment: passing .ozn file means I am using solns2out, this is taking the main time. But not able to figure out the reason.

Comment: @RajatGupta, Can you post you're output statement? I'm afraid we won't be able to diagnose the problem without it

Comment: I found out the problem in solns2out, I was passing large arrays in a function to print the strings. Currently it is a open issue on GitHub about solns2out that it takes so much memory for this case and never free it. Link is https://github.com/MiniZinc/libminizinc/issues/145       There is no solution to this issue yet.